# indicate the type of probability - priori, subjective or empirical

Tags: probability

indicate the type of probability - priori, subjective or empirical.
The next toss of a fair coin will be heads

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Please add the self-study tag, read it’s wiki, and post what progress you’ve made. We’re happy to help with homework problems, but we do handle them a bit differently than we handle other questions.

Answer (score 3):

It is unclear exactly what you are asking, but I'll try to answer as best I can.

A Priori probability assumes equal probability to all possible outcomes. If there are N possible outcomes, then *a priori* probability (sometimes also called theoretical probability or classical probability) says that the probability of any given outcome is $1/N$. Flipping a coin has two possible outcomes, so the probability of the next toss of a fair coin being heads is 1/2.

Empirical probability involves observing many trials, and assigns probabilities based on the frequency of observed outcomes. If you flip a coin 100 times and 51 times it falls on heads, you might say that the empirical probability of heads is 0.51. The more trials you perform, the closer the empirical probability will get to 0.5 in this particular coin flipping example.

Subjective probability is an opinion. It may even be based on a fallacious belief held by the individual assigning the probability. The statement "the next toss of a fair coin will be heads" if taken to be an absolute statement implies that there is a 100% chance that the next toss will be heads. This is a subjective opinion not supported by either a priori probability or empirical trials. Therefore, the statement in question is an example of subjective probability.

Comment: It is possible I don't understand what you mean by *a priori probability*, but it may be a confusion of the notion of a uniform prior distribution in particular in contrast to the notion of a prior distribution itself. In Bayesian probability [we often choose uniform priors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_indifference), but we don't have to. Sometimes we choose Gaussians when previous data suggests it, other times we choose [Jeffrey's prior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeffreys_prior). Please clarify.

Comment: Ah, I found a [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_priori_probability) on it. In this sense of *a priori* one 'can' choose a uniform probability measure, but other probability measures can be chosen. The [principle of indifference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_indifference) is useful, but not the only way of assigning probability measures from first principles.